# Need to communicate with a TCP/IP locally hosted server in Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, tcp

I have the following situation.
I have a locally hosted TCP/IP server running on port 8090
I need to be able to send it a command from my android application. The server should take that command and return a set of information that I need.
I don't have access to the server or server logs.

What I've been trying

Simple Socket connection which seems to connect just fine. However after using printWriter and sending the server my command. The BufferedReader gets stuck on reader.readLine() or .read(). I assume that the server isnt responding to my command, the writer isnt writing properly(How do I tell?) or this method isn't correct for the situation at hand.

Been trying to do it with URL and HTTPURLConnection objects but I'm not sure that I'm doing it properly.

I do have code that I can post however I don't think its relevant yet.

What do you suggest?

Requested Code

```
                        Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.16", 8090);

                        //Send message to server
                        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                        String number = "message";

                        String sendMessage = number + "\n";
                        bw.write(sendMessage);
                        bw.flush();
                        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        //Get the return message from the server
                        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        String message = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
```

Comment: Can you debug the server?  It sounds like the solution will be found by seeing what the server is doing/receiving.

Comment: If the receiver tries to read a line you should be shure that the sender sent a line or closed the socket after sending. Then all goes ok. So what are you doing instead?

Comment: `have code that I can post however I don't think its relevant yet`. Of course it's relevant as your code is not yet ok.

Comment: Ok, Ill show you what ive got

Comment: `to send it a command from my android application`. Where is your android application running?

Comment: `Requested Code`. Where exactly are you executing/calling this code?

Comment: `I have a locally hosted TCP/IP server running on port 8090`. AND `trying to do it with URL and HTTPURLConnection objects`. Well that would only make sense if your server was a webserver using the http protocol. Now does it?

Comment: Calling code from button click atm

Answer (score 1):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. You can read more from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: The info in this answer has nothing to do with the problem. I wonder who upvoted it.

Comment: yea, its not testing on a simulator, its testing on an android device on the same network as the PC hosting the server.